# Only ask for filename if one has not been input

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, savefiledialog

I am using C# and a winform and am saving data to a .xlsx on a button click event.  I have a unique situation that I am not sure how to code for....
If the form is still displayed and the user clicks the button, I want it to prompt for a file name and save location.  **BUT** if the form has not been closed and the user clicks the button a second time, I want .xlsx to be saved in the same location and with the same filename and over write with no prompt.

This is the syntax I use to prompt for save name and location, but how do I check to determine if a filename/save location has already been input and if it has do not prompt again?

```
private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    save.RestoreDirectory = true;
    save.Title = "Select save location file name";
    save.DefaultExt = "xlsx";

    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(save.FileName);
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                package.Save();
            }
        }
        catch { Messagebox.Show("An error has occured"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this globally:

```
public string Filename;
```

Then change your subroutine like this:

```
private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Filename))
    {
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    save.RestoreDirectory = true;
    save.Title = "Select save location file name";
    save.DefaultExt = "xlsx";

    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            Filename = save.FileName;
            var file = new FileInfo(save.FileName);
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                package.Save();
            }
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("An error has occured"); }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(Filename);
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            package.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: globally meaning under the class name but above the first method?

Comment: Yes so it's not in a method but is inside the class.

Comment: Ah. I copied the code from the original which had the wrong Messagebox. I noticed it doesn't have a closing bracket either.

Comment: You're duplicating code, and not using try catch in the second save

Answer (score 3):

So, whether the data has a set filename is a part of the state of the class.  Inside the class where you have `btnOne_Click`, just define a string with the filename, defaulted to null:

```
string filepath = null;
```

Then, in your `btnOne_Click`, you want to check for the filepath.  If it's not there, open the saveAs dialog.  After that, if filepath is set, just save.  It will be restructured like this:

```
private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (filepath == null)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        save.RestoreDirectory = true;
        save.Title = "Select save location file name";
        save.DefaultExt = "xlsx";

        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            filepath = save.FileName;
        }
    }

    if (filepath != null) 
    {
        try
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(filepath);
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                package.Save();
            }
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("An error has occured"; }
    }
}
```

This logical structure gives you standard behavior for when a user presses a save button.  If they cancel the saveAs dialog, then the save is aborted and the filename state is not changed.